# Pyspark Operations are Slower than Hive

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 3 dataframes df1,  df2 and df3. 
Each dataframe has approximately 3million rows. df1 and df3 has apprx. 8 columns. df2 has only 3 columns.
(source text file of df1 is approx 600MB size)

**These are the operations performed:**

- df_new=df1 left join df2 ->group by df1 columns->select df1 columns, first(df2 columns)
- df_final = df_new outer join df3
- df_split1 =  df_final filtered using condition1
- df_split2 = df_final filtered using condition2
- write df_split1,df_split2 into a single table after performing different operations on both dataframes

This entire process takes 15mins in pyspark 1.3.1, with default partition value = 10, executor memory = 30G,  driver memory = 10G and I have used cache() wherever necessary.

But when I use hive queries, this hardly takes 5 mins. Is there any particular reason why my dataframe operations are slow and is there any way I can improve the performance?

Comment: Even thought you are caching. The data needs to load into spark whereas they already in hive.

Comment: How do you describe your condition1/condition2?

Comment: does this mean hive is faster than spark?

Comment: Conditions are ColX is null, ColY is not null

Comment: Why do you use such outdated Spark version? There is huge performance gap between 1.3 and 1.6

Comment: My employer is using that version. Upgrade is not possible for next few months.

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful with the use of `JOIN`.

`JOIN` in spark can be really expensive. Especially if the join is between two dataframes. You can avoid expensive operations by re-partition the two dataframes on the same column or by using the same partitioner.